# python datetime for git commit time?

Tags: python, git, dulwich

I'm having a (django) db that wants datetime objects, and I'd like to feed it data from git commits.

Now git commits have that "not really a timezone" offset thingie.

What's the correct way to get a python datetime? Any luck with getting timezones right?

I'm thinking about

```
datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(commit.commit_time)
```

I'm using dulwich right now, but that seems to be a side note.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a "FixedOffset" timezone as suggested in the datetime documentation. Unfortunately it looks like `datetime` doesn't include this class itself, so you'll have to copy it into your code.

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html . Specifically, look for `FixedOffset`.